# Retrieve Attributes of child level object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loopback

My code is as following.My objective is to retrieve first name of student from the function object given below. I did try JSON.Stringify and JSON.Parse

```
EnrolledSessions.find({
    where: {
        aproval_status: 'pending',
        tutor_id: tutorId
    },
    include: {
        relation:'StudentRelation'
    }
},
function (err, sessions) {
    if (err) cb(err);
    if (!err) {
        for(var i in sessions) {
            var item = sessions[i];
            console.log(item.StudentRelation);
        }
    }
});
```

And here are results for `console.log(item.StudentRelation);` from above

```
{ [Function: bound ]
  getAsync: [Function: bound ]
  update: [Function: bound ],
  destroy: [Function: bound ],
  create: [Function: bound ],
  build: [Function: bound ],
  _targetClass: 'erudoUser' }
{ [Function: bound ]
  getAsync: [Function: bound ]
  update: [Function: bound ],
  destroy: [Function: bound ],
  create: [Function: bound ],
  build: [Function: bound ],
  _targetClass: 'erudoUser' }
{ [Function: bound ]
  getAsync: [Function: bound ]
  update: [Function: bound ],
  destroy: [Function: bound ],
  create: [Function: bound ],
  build: [Function: bound ],
  _targetClass: 'erudoUser' }
{ [Function: bound ]
  getAsync: [Function: bound ]
  update: [Function: bound ],
  destroy: [Function: bound ],
  create: [Function: bound ],
  build: [Function: bound ],
  _targetClass: 'erudoUser' }
```

Function Object which I am trying to loop through

```
[ { coursesession_id: 574fc6baa09d9bc4050b974e,
        student_id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37,
        tutor_id: 574fbff2179281fc15c5db3d,
        aproval_status: 'pending',
        start_date: Thu Jun 02 2016 11:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        duration: '06:00',
        session_type: 'One To One',
        enteredtopic_name: 'addition',
        payment_status: 'paid',
        course_completed: false,
        TxnId: 'IKGqrpI6IHnxIFEJsFt53EIqw',
        id: 574fc6baa09d9bc4050b974f,
        StudentRelation:
         { user_type: 'student',
           firstname: 'Student',
           lastname: 'Ps',
           active_status: true,
           email: 'sikha.p91@gmail.com',
           grade: '574fbeb2179281fc15c5db34',
           syllabus: '574fbea9179281fc15c5db33',
           mobile: '8157897518',
           place: 'kannru',
           password: '$2a$10$YIUVCclA6.vBeePZuMY7uu.6lYr..fQD4o9dSY7uF9FmgkTWAqq3i',

           emailVerified: true,
           id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37 } },
      { coursesession_id: 574fde1dc59f447c1235007b,
        student_id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37,
        tutor_id: 574fbff2179281fc15c5db3d,
        aproval_status: 'pending',
        start_date: Mon Jun 13 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        duration: '01:00',
        session_type: 'One To One',
        enteredtopic_name: 'integration',
        payment_status: 'paid',
        course_completed: false,
        TxnId: 'KpDGHtLwIK6D3zIICtIGoL46p',
        id: 574fde1dc59f447c1235007c,
        StudentRelation:
         { user_type: 'student',
           firstname: 'Student',
           lastname: 'Ps',
           active_status: true,
           email: 'sikha.p91@gmail.com',
           grade: '574fbeb2179281fc15c5db34',
           syllabus: '574fbea9179281fc15c5db33',
           mobile: '8157897518',
           place: 'kannru',
           password: '$2a$10$YIUVCclA6.vBeePZuMY7uu.6lYr..fQD4o9dSY7uF9FmgkTWAqq3i',

           emailVerified: true,
           id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37 } },
      { coursesession_id: 57511d25388d2150161559de,
        student_id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37,
        tutor_id: 574fbff2179281fc15c5db3d,
        aproval_status: 'pending',
        start_date: Fri Jun 03 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        duration: '06:00',
        session_type: 'One To One',
        enteredtopic_name: 'multiplication',
        payment_status: 'paid',
        course_completed: false,
        TxnId: 'voyn9oqyG14ItzzwqHI4GxM1o',
        id: 57511d25388d2150161559df,
        StudentRelation:
         { user_type: 'student',
           firstname: 'Student',
           lastname: 'Ps',
           active_status: true,
           email: 'sikha.p91@gmail.com',
           grade: '574fbeb2179281fc15c5db34',
           syllabus: '574fbea9179281fc15c5db33',
           mobile: '8157897518',
           place: 'kannru',
           password: '$2a$10$YIUVCclA6.vBeePZuMY7uu.6lYr..fQD4o9dSY7uF9FmgkTWAqq3i',

           emailVerified: true,
           id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37 } },
      { coursesession_id: 57511d25388d2150161559de,
        student_id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37,
        tutor_id: 574fbff2179281fc15c5db3d,
        aproval_status: 'pending',
        start_date: Sat Jun 04 2016 09:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
        duration: '06:00',
        session_type: 'One To One',
        enteredtopic_name: 'multiplication',
        payment_status: 'paid',
        course_completed: false,
        TxnId: 'voyn9oqyG14ItzzwqHI4GxM1o',
        id: 57511d25388d2150161559e0,
        StudentRelation:
         { user_type: 'student',
           firstname: 'Student',
           lastname: 'Ps',
           active_status: true,
           email: 'sikha.p91@gmail.com',
           grade: '574fbeb2179281fc15c5db34',
           syllabus: '574fbea9179281fc15c5db33',
           mobile: '8157897518',
           place: 'kannru',
           password: '$2a$10$YIUVCclA6.vBeePZuMY7uu.6lYr..fQD4o9dSY7uF9FmgkTWAqq3i',

           emailVerified: true,
           id: 574fbf10179281fc15c5db37 } } ]
```

Comment: what do you get when you print console.log(sessions);

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [toJSON](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter#Includefilter-Accessincludedobjects) to convert the returned model instance with related items into a plain JSON object.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I ended up having to do exactly as Ivan suggested, and it works. I'm not super happy with the solution, as it makes for a lot of intermediate data handling, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Above answer of Stringfy will work but that is a hack .

this is the proper loopback way

```
   let info = item.getAsync().then((res) => cb(null,res));
```